KeyVault replication - Do I have to manually create second KV in paired region?
I cannot deduce from documentation whether I need to create a KeyVault in second region for the KeyVault to replicate and failover in case of region outage or if it's done behind the scene.
I have a stack in US east and a copy US West - Everything goes through US East, US West is there, idle, to failover in case US East is completely out. I have a third stack with FrontDoor deployed to monitor this. Inside this stack there is also a KeyVault (US east) that has secrets needed for apps to connect with each other. Now if US east goes down, FrontDoor should detect it and failover my origin group to resoruces on US west. Will Azure replicate my KeyVault automatically to US West and hook it up to my stack in US west? How can I test if KeyVault will replicate correctly and hook up to other services in US West if US East goes down?
I've stopped apps to test whether FrontDoor detecs they are unreachable, for databases I know I have to set up a copy in another region manually and setup a failover group, but for KeyVault it looks like it works outside the box but I cannot find a way to test it?

Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/disaster-recovery-guidance?

I did, it says "in the rare event that an entire Azure region is unavailable, the requests that you make of Azure Key Vault in that region are automatically routed (failed over) to a secondary region. " But will Azure by itself create a new KV in US West, replicate the contents and route all my services to it. In such case I don't know why this KV can't just be visible in read-only mode as a resource deployed in US West so that I can see it is configured correctly.

as per the documentation the contents of your key vault in East US are replicated both within the region and to the paired region (West US).

From Azure Key Vault availability and redundancy:
The way that Key Vault replicates your data depends on the specific region that your vault is in, i.e. if the region is paired with another region or not.
Data replication
Regions East US and West US are paired - this means that the contents of your key vault are replicated both within the region and to the paired region. This approach ensures high durability of your keys and secrets.
Failover within a region
If individual components within the key vault service fail, alternate components within the region step in to serve your request to make sure that there's no degradation of functionality. You don't need to take any action—the process happens automatically and will be transparent to you.
Similarly, in a region where your vault is replicated across availability zones, if an availability zone is unavailable then Azure Key Vault automatically redirects your requests to another availability zone to ensure high availability.
Failover across regions
If you're in a region that automatically replicates your key vault to a secondary region, then in the rare event that an entire Azure region is unavailable, the requests that you make of Azure Key Vault in that region are automatically routed (failed over) to a secondary region. When the primary region is available again, requests are routed back (failed back) to the primary region. Again, you don't need to take any action because this happens automatically.
